# Fading multiple divs with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two or in future may be more divs with background images in css. I would like to fade them in and out in a loop.

I am trying to do something like this but it doesn`t work.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var divs = $('.fade');


function fade() {
    var current = $('.current');
    var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    
    if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }
    
    var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);
    
    next.stop().fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
    
    current.stop().fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(fade, 2500);
    });
}

fade();
```

```css
#one {
   background-image: url("Test_bg.jpg");
margin-top: -150px;
min-height: 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
}

#two {
   background-image: url("Test_bg1.jpg");
margin-top: -150px;
min-height: 100%;
display: block;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="fade current">
</div>
    <div id="two" class="fade">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mising `})` at the end with causes syntax error

```js
$(window).load(function(){
var divs = $('.fade');


function fade() {
    var current = $('.current');
    var currentIndex = divs.index(current),
        nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex >= divs.length) {
        nextIndex = 0;
    }

    var next = divs.eq(nextIndex);

    next.stop().fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });

    current.stop().fadeOut(2000, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('current');
        setTimeout(fade, 2500);
    });
}

fade();
})
```

```css
#one {
  color: red
}

#two {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="fade current">a
</div>
<div id="two" class="fade">b
</div>
```